# c# datagridview graphic problems cell.style.backcolor

Tags: c#, windows

On my dev maschine this code looks nice.

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dgListe.Rows)
            {
                if (dgr.Cells["ColorName"].Value != "" && dgr.Cells["ColorName"].Value != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell drgc in dgr.Cells) {
                        drgc.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName(dgr.Cells["ColorName"].Value.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
```

is working as good as

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dgListe.Rows)
            {
                if (dgr.Cells["ColorName"].Value != "" && dgr.Cells["ColorName"].Value != null)
                {

                    DataGridViewCellStyle zs = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                    zs = dgr.DefaultCellStyle;
                    zs.BackColor = Color.FromName(dgr.Cells["ColorName"].Value.ToString());
                    dgr.DefaultCellStyle = zs;
                }
            }
```

But on some pc´s do something like a shaddow copies? of it´s self while scrolling the list. (att. screenshot)

OK: (new PC´s)
->

[image]

N.OK.: (old PC´s)
->

[image]

Info: Dotnotfx 4 client framework, std. winform project, any cpu

Answer (score 0):

Is a hack, but it worked for me:

Add default BackColor (like White) to the datagridview before you format it.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help somebody. The Reason of this problem may be alpha channel in argb. So, if you change the color creation method without alpha (as I done), the problem can be solved